# Уведомление со встроенной ссылкой Plyer, Python

Tags: python

Возможно ли с помощью Plyer послать уведомление в центр уведомлений windows 10 со встроенной ссылкой?
Ну чтобы когда я кликал на выскакивающее уведомление открывался браузер(или в открытом браузере открывалась новая вкладка) и в нем открывался нужный мне сайт.
Если нет то можете ли что-нибудь посоветовать для реализации этого?